# If I get a cross-origin-request-blocked error on my front-end, why does the request still seem to get processed

Tags: express, cross-domain

I was under the impression that cross-origin requests getting blocked was primarily a security thing that prevents evil websites from getting or updating information on your web service.

I've noticed however that even though a request gets blocked on my front-end, the code still executes in the backend.

For example:

```
import express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 80

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next()
});

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
    console.log("test1")
    res.json({
        data: "Hello"
    })
    console.log("test2")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

If my frontend then makes a request the express service, the request will fail because of `cross-origin` but the express service will still log

```
test1
test2
```

Should express block the service from continuing to run since the origin is not permitted? Isn't a security threat if the express code still executes even if the front-end gets an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of CORs requests in the browser implementation and which is used depends on the specific request being made.

For requests that do not require pre-flight, the request is made to the back-end and then the browser examines the resulting headers to see if the CORs request is permitted or not.  If it's not permitted (as in the case you show), then the result of the request is blocked from the client so it can't see the result of the request (even though the server fully processed it).

As best I can tell from what you show, everything here is working as expected. The request is considered a "simple request" and does not require preflight.  Browser-based Javascript will not be allowed to get results from this route if it's not the same origin.

---

For requests that do require preflight (there's a list of things in a request that can trigger preflight), then the browser will first ask the server if the request is permitted by sending an OPTIONS request to the same route.  The server then decides whether to allow the request or not.  If the browser gets permission from the server, then it sends the real request.

You can see what triggers preflight [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests).

Presumably, the browser doesn't use preflight all the time because it's less efficient (requiring double the requests).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense to me now. The one thing I was thinking of was "well what if a malicious site calls a dangerous request like `/delete-account`" or something like that. CORs may block a returned result but it could still be destructive to the user. But I suppose it's still safer to have CORs then not. And that makes sense about efficiency.

Comment: @Cameron - A destructive command like `/delete-account` should require some form of authentication credential before the server carries it out.  It's also possible for a server to require things in the request before it will process it (like a specific content-type or custom header) that would force the browser to pre-flight it.  Keep in mind that CORs protections do not protect your server at all from malicious agents.  They only prevent other web-sites from surreptitiously using your web servers in their client-side web pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation :)